# Rhythmbox last.fm unsupported format error

Tags: rhythmbox

I don't understand why I keep getting unsupported format errors when using the last.fm plugin in rhythmbox. It seems to happen every time I try to play a song only one or two tracks advanced.. if I try to play a song that's three or more tracks ahead it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a bug, you can report it here: [Bugs : “rhythmbox” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox).